# Finding patterns across rows of data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to find patterns across rows of a data.table while still maintaining the linkages of data across the rows. Here is a reduced example:

```
Row ID Value
1   C  1000
2   A  500
3   T  -200
4   B  5000
5   T  -900
6   A  300
```

I would like to search for all instances of "ATB" in successive rows and output the integers from the value column. Ideally, I want to bin the number of instances as well. The output table would look like this:

```
String Frequency Value1 Value2 Value 3
ATB      1        500   -200    5000
CAT      1        1000   500    -200
```

Since the data.table packages seems to be oriented towards providing operations on a column or row-wise basis I thought this should be possible. However, I haven't the slightest idea where to start. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show a few more lines with expected output

Comment: Based on the expected output showed, you selected the first 3 rows for `CAT`, 2:4 for `ATB`, so what about `3:5` and so on...

Comment: If you were searching only for "ATB", how did you end up with "CAT"?

Comment: And how will this look like if there several `ATB` combinations? You have `Frequency` there, so you want to combine somehow their values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library("plyr")
library("stringr")
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Row ID Value
                 1   C  1000
                 2   A  500
                 3   T  -200
                 4   B  5000
                 5   T  -900
                 6   A  300
                 7   C  200
                 8   A  700
                 9   T  -500")
sought <- c("ATB", "CAT", "NOT")
ids <- paste(df$ID, collapse = "")
ldply(sought, function(id) {
    found <- str_locate_all(ids, id)
      if (nrow(found[[1]])) {
            vals <- outer(found[[1]][,"start"], 0:2, function(x, y) df$Value[x + y])
      } else {
            vals <- as.list(rep(NA, 3))
      }
      data.frame(ID = id, Count = str_count(ids, id),
                 setNames(as.data.frame(vals), paste0("Value", 1:3)))
})
```

Here's a solution using `stringr` and `plyr`. The ids are collapsed into a single string, all instances of each target located and then a data frame constructed with the relevant columns.

Comment: When I run your example, I get an error in FUN(x[[1]], ..) : object 'x' not found. Also, I want values for every instance of "CAT" in the string.

Comment: @krisadastra sorry there was a typo; `x` should have been `df`. I've also now made it handle multiple CATs! (And any other strings. )

Comment: I figured it out - it's a typo - "x" should be "df".

Comment: Wow, this looks great! I see that you changed it to handle multiple CATs. This is exactly what I needed. The collapse and str_locate functions are new to me so thanks for letting me know about them!